# In a Linux user space process what is the address of the vsyscall page?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I would like to acquire the address of the vsyscall page for my own uses.  I only have two ideas here: alter the compiler to store this information in some known location after it is given to __start, or read /proc/[pid]/maps.  I really don't want to read /proc/ as that is slow and shouldn't be necessary.  I also don't want to make compiler modifications.  Does anyone have an alternative?  Is there a symbol I should know about?

Its at the point I'm tempted to stuff this functionality into an ioctl call in a module I've developed as part of this work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a stab in the dark:

If you can determine at what address the process stack began, then you can possibly find the parameters which were provided to `__start`.  You might then access the parameters via pointers of the appropriate type set to the corresponding offsets from the initial stack pointer.

According to the article [How main() is executed on Linux , by Hyouck "Hawk" Kim](http://tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/84/hawk.html), the first few instructions of `__start` will write the initial arguments in a deterministic way before calling `__libc_start_main`.

Obviously any approach like this is platform-specific and subject to instability if the implementation of `__start` were changed.